# Bootstrap 3.3.1 Spacing options not working. Anyone know what could be wrong?

Tags: css

Have tried many of the examples around here and am coming up with nothing working. Not sure where to go from here or how to troubleshoot. Can't find any classes as "mt" or "pb" for example, either.

Anyone else have this issue before? Am I missing something obvious? Have no clue.

Comment: "mt" and "pb" are classes apart of [Bootstrap 4's spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/) not 3. It's also beneficial to provide a test case from a jsfiddle or embedding in SO to show your problem in action.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. The documentation did not mention that, but I notice now in the link it contains “docs/4.1” so yeah you must be right.

Comment: You can read about the migration and differences between 3 and 4 [on the migrate page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/#utilities)

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 4 comes with those [spacing utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/) and not Bootstrap 3 as documented in their [migration pages](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/#utilities) section.

Comment: Ok great. Thanks again l3fty.